# Phonegap non debug mode and signing with license key

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I've completed a app in phonegap and would like to publish this on the google app store. Every time I download the apk file its in debug mode. How do I go about signing it with a key or keystore to get this to upload into google play as google will not upload it into my account in debug mode.

I'm doing something wrong but can not see how in build.phonegap.com you can sign the app?

Please help

Thanks

Comment: do you have eclipse installed with android required plugins?

Comment: No I'm just using phonegap build website to compile the app

Comment: ohk see my answer. That will help you to make it solve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this command from the terminal or command prompt to generate keystore file:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myAppKey.keystore -alias myAppKey -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```

This will generate `myAppKey.keystore` file.

That you have to upload at `build.phonegap.com` site under your application settings.
There you will get `signing settings` so add your `keystore` and then select that signing key for your application.

By this phonegap will regenerate android builds and you will get APK which will be used to publish in the google play market.

**REFERENCE :**

[how Google suggests creating an Android keystore](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert)

Comment: @Grimlockz which os u r using?

Comment: @Grimlockz let me check for this os generally it works with mac and windows.

Comment: @Grimlockz see I have added reference. It shows `JDK` environment must be installed on your pc to get keystore.

Comment: i've run keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 but build.phonegap.com is not accepting the keystore file on upload

Comment: @Grimlockz does phonegap showing any errors while uploading keystore?

Comment: Keystore alias not recognized

Comment: @Grimlockz that's great to hear.

Comment: Getting Illegal option: –genkey : Wrong hyphen in the command example. Edited.

Comment: Awesome, you just saved me from an hour of reading Google's documents.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the illegal option too - something about copy/pasting from the post above is causing that. If you delete the '-' characters and type them manually using the '-' on your keyboard then it works :)