# Phonegap/Cordova Debugg chrome Inspect

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

just wondering when in debugging i can see everything in Chrome:inspect. But after deployment on Play Store/App Store.

Could the App elements/log etc still be viewed via Chrome:inspect etc???

Or then it would be embedded in the root and can't be viewed??

In Phonegap, i dont have enable debugging selected. I read this thread [Phonegap non debug mode and signing with license key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629085/phonegap-non-debug-mode-and-signing-with-license-key)
So i just add an signing key for Android, and package that APK, then i wont be able to view it through Chrome:inspect etc??

Comment: If you don't have hydration active you shouldn't be able to debug the app once you upload it to google play, but the best thing you can do is to upload your app to google play (as beta or alpha) and check it yourself